# compress video into fragments

Tags: flutter, dart, compression

I am trying to compress videos into fragments with the help of `ffmpeg_kit_flutter` plugin, however I keep getting a `return code 1`

```
    void compressFile(String videoPath) {
    String outputDirectory = "path/to/output";
    String outputFileNamePattern = "output_%03d.mp4";
    double segmentDuration = 10.0; // Segment duration in seconds
    String outputPath = "$outputDirectory/$outputFileNamePattern";
    String splitCommand =
        "-i $videoPath -c copy -f segment -segment_time $segmentDuration $outputPath";
    FFmpegKitConfig.enableLogs();
    FFmpegKit.executeAsync(splitCommand).then((session) async {
      ReturnCode? returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();
      if (returnCode != null && returnCode.isValueSuccess()) {
        print("Video splitting successful!");
        // Do something with the split video pieces
      } else {
        print("Video splitting failed. Error: ${returnCode.toString()}");
        // Handle the failure
      }
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }
```

This is how my videoPath look like `/data/user/0/com.example.ceenit_flutter/cache/e8a4e4b60a8aacf43a42f9f674f942b1_1685571473743.mp4`